# How to combine cer and key to generate jks file

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am new to certificates and its conversions from one form to other. I also tried exploring but finding it a bit difficult to interpret exact info. I got two files `gtcloud.cer` (certificate) and `gtcloud.key` (private key starts with `BEGIN_PRIVATE_KEY`, ends with `END_PRIVATE_KEY`).

Now I want to merge these two to generate a single JKS file which I can use in my java application.

Is there any GUI based software or we have to use openssl for this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because this is a programming site. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/) explains it. I was able to use it successfully.

*Summary:* Use the following two commands.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in [path to certificate] -inkey [path to private key] -certfile [path to certificate ] -out testkeystore.p12
```

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore testkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

**Update**: 
If you need to convert you certificate to the `pem` format, use the following command:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in [path to certificate ] -out myCert.pem
```

Also, here are some good information about the existing formats: [Certificate standards](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Always include summary of relevant pieces in questions/answers, in case the linked site is down (or gone in 2 years).

Comment: thank you for quick pointers but I am getting error in loading the certificates and prompt is not showing helpful logs.

 `C:\imp docs\Lab Access\APT Taiwan\certificates\testing>openssl pkcs12 -export -in gtcloud.cer -inkey gtcloud.key -certfile gtcloud.cer -out testkeystore.p12
 unable to load certificates`


how can I debug what went wrong ?

Comment: example in that site uses .pem for private key and certificate. Do I have to convert my private key from .key to .pem and certificate from .cer to .pem?

Comment: I had to convert my certificate from .cer to .pem(openssl x509 -inform der -in gtcloud.cer -out gtcloud_1.pem) and private key from .key to .pem(by just renaming). After this conversion I used two openssl commands mentioned above and got the necessary jks! Appreciate your help!!