# create .jks file with .cer and .key

Tags: jks

I found a similar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264534/how-to-combine-cer-and-key-to-generate-jks-file) to my question but I had further queries so asking this question again.

I will be getting .cer and .key and would want to create one .jks file. So, according to the link (correct me if I am wrong),

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in [path to certificate] -inkey [path to private key] -certfile [path to certificate ] -out testkeystore.p12
```

We first create a .p12 file from .cer and .key. Is that right? If yes, why do we have two "path to certificate"?

In the next step,

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore testkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

We create .jks file from the .p12.

1. What parameter can I use so that I can set the password for .jks
   file?
2. In the second step its using keytool, can I not do it using
       openssl? Is keytool the only way to generate .jks file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the jks password you should add `-deststorepass password -destkeypass password`. It's actually possible to use two different passwords: one for the store as a whole and a different one for the private key - though they are often the same.

Keytool is the only way to make a JKS.

Note that JKS is now a deprecated format - in favour of PKCS12! So you may just want to keep your keystore in PKCS12 format.

Openssl could use your cer file for two reasons: to extract you certficate, and to extract the certificates used to sign your certificate. Hence why you need to specify it twice.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your last suggestion on "So you may just want to keep your keystore in PKCS12 format."? Also, why on the first step it is asking certificate path twice?

Comment: Since JKS is going away, I was questioning why you would need to convert from PKCS12 (.p12) to JKS. Why not just use `testkeystore.p12`. Whatever application you need the JKS for should probably also have an option to accept PKCS12.

Comment: The application has a UI parameter to accept only .jks file. Hence it should be .jks. Can you please tell why do we have multiple "path to certificate"? What value is that adding?

Comment: See my edited answer. You should tell the application author that JKS is deprecated, and ask them to support PKCS12 as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Will try it tomorrow

Comment: I am having some issues executing openssl command. for Path to certificate, I specified: C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\my.cer but its saying certificate not found.

Comment: First, I'd move all your certificates etc out of the openssl folder, into a working folder (e.g. under c:\users\). Then cd to that folder. You will have t type the full path of openssl, but the cert files will be in your working directory. Then update the question with a listing of dir and the openssl output.

Comment: Too bad hadoop developer didn't read your message. they might have allow for use of pkcs12 :-(